# How to tackle different sample size in the training set in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, svm

I have to train a SVM for a classification problem. I have some strings that are the paths in a deterministic finite automata (DFA). If the alphabet is -01-   then possible strings are 011101110  or 0110 for example. The purpose of classifier (SVM) is the correct prediction (label) of unseen strings like accepting or rejecting(label 1 or label -1, binary classification). 
The problem is that the strings have different lenghts. How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3):

A SVM classifier requires a fixed-length feature vector, i.e., all feature vectors must have the same length.  There are multiple solutions:

- Pad out the strings to fixed length.
- Choose a different set of features, so that there is a fixed number of features.
- Pick a fixed number $k$, and look at windows of length $k$ (i.e., substrings of length $k$).  Classify each window of length $k$ using your SVM, then combine those results somehow (e.g., majority vote).
- Use a different classifier, such as a recurrent neural network (e.g., LSTM).  See also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/16115/8560 for more possibilities.

It's hard to say what will be most appropriate for your particular situation, without knowing more about your learning task.

---

Based on your subsequent comments, it sounds like you want to learn a DFA.  There's lots written on learning DFAs, using Angluin's algorithm, SAT solvers, or other methods.  Follow [the link above](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/16115/8560) for some entry points into the literature on that.  I don't think a SVM  is the right tool for that job -- this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).

Comment: I must build a classifier that  is able to predict if an unseen string is accepting or rejecting for the underlying DFA. Practically
 the builded SVM have to be a good approximation of regular language(DFA) captured(you hope) from string of trainining set. I was forced to use SVM. What could be a good concrete technique?

Comment: @Umbert, see last paragraph in edited answer.

Comment: I have to implement in the active learning (L*,Observation Pack algorithms) an oracle approximate. I don't want learn exactly a  dfa from strings ma learn in a approximate way the dfa(the language) with svm from strings like this I use the classifier for do approximate membership and equivalences queries. I also think that SVMs are not perfectly suitable but I have been forced to use them.So what could be the best technique to do equal string length in my case? (I do not think there is literature, it's a specific problem. But is there no such 
 similar (no exact) example?)

Comment: @Umbert, what forces you to use a SVM?  It seems like it might to understand the source and nature of that requirement. If it helps, there are ways to learn an approximate DFA (e.g., choose a random sample of the training set and learn a DFA for that, say using SAT; or other methods are possible).

Comment: No underying knowledge, but the requirement is imposed for research purposes. Finally thanks for the various answers